# Count number of occurrences of 2 values in different columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
V1  | V2  | V3 | V4
 1  | 4   | 10 | 0
 10 | 1   | 1  | 4
 NA | 1   | 4  | 3
```

I'd like to count the occurrence of values 1 & 4 
how many times the value "1" occurred where "4" came in the very next column.

Expected result:

```
> [1] 3
```

Comment: If you have 1-4 in one row two times it will be  2 or 1 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using paste with collapse then str_count:

```
sum(stringr::str_count(do.call(paste, c(cbind(NA, d, NA), sep = ",")), ",1,4,"))
```

We are adding NA columns to data as first and last columns: `cbind(NA, d, NA)`, so that str_count doesn't match on `"101,4"` or `"1,41"`.

Comment: If i understand right, your version count only if 4 in next colunm , not in any next colunm.  And "1,41" also will be count as "1,4,"

Comment: @Batanichek The OP has stated "in the very next column".

Comment: @DavidArenburg thank you, yes there is a performance gain, 190mins vs 260mins, updated the post.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can easily vectorize this and avoid string manipulators (which can be potentially dangerous for exact matches)

```
sum(d[-ncol(d)] == 1 & d[-1] == 4)
# [1] 3
```

Comment: Sorry, I was confusing data.frames and matrices (I usually write a `,` when selecting columns, I easily confuse myself). +1

Comment: @Axeman, yeah I usually don't write it so one column data.frames won't become a vector and break the code. Though in this case it will work both ways.

Answer (score 2):

#### Read in data

```
d <- read.table(header = TRUE, sep = '|', text = '
V1  | V2  | V3 | V4
1| 4 | 10 | 0
10| 1 | 1 | 4
NA| 1  | 4 | 3')
```

#### Function that matches patterns in vectors

```
count_pattern <- function(x, pattern) {
  e <- embed(x, length(pattern))
  f <- apply(e, 1, function(r) all(r == rev(pattern)))
  return(sum(f, na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

`embed` makes a time series, which makes it easier to compare the pattern against all subsets of the vector that needs to be tested.

#### Apply to your data

```
rows <- apply(d, 1, count_pattern, c(1, 4))
sum(rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope the below could should couls answer your question. I know, it is not an optimized code. but should be helpful.

```
> data
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  1  4 10  0
2 10  1  1  4
3 NA  1  4  3

>for (j in 1:(ncol(data)-1)){

  for (i in 1:nrow(data)){

    if(!is.na(data[i,j]) & !is.na(data[i,j+1]))
      {
      if (data[i,j]== 1 & data[i,j+1]==4) {count = count+1}
      }
  }
}

>print(count)
```

Comment: Hey Ravi, I am getting this error `Error in count + 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Comment: I tried converting the dataframe to Numeric then I got this error `Error in 1:(ncol(n2) - 1) : argument of length 0`

Comment: Sorry. I forgot add one line.. Please initialize the variable "count" before entering the for  loop. count =0